# Function nested itself in the prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance

**Question1**:

I was experimenting with prototypes of the objects and constructors in JS, when I've noticed that:

```
function f(a) {
  this.a = a;
  this.x = 1
}

function f2(a) {
  this.a = a;
  this.x = 4
}

f2.__proto__ = f(9);

var of2 = new f2(4);
```

somehow makes f2() nesting itself in its `prototype -> constructor`, so I've got infinite nesting (as below):

[image]

Could anyone explain such behaviour, please? Or maybe it's just an error, that is caused by tool?

**Question2**:
So if it's normal, how does that work in the memory? Is it working on references, or just insert prototype to constructor, constructor to prototype an so on? If the second hypothesis is true, why my computers memory is still fine and not burning?

Comment: Prototype object has reference to Constructor it belongs to. And Constructor has property prototype. Then Prototype has reference to Constructor, and so on. In other words `f.prototype.constructor === f`. So answer to your question: this is normal.

Comment: **Dont set internal properties!**

Comment: `f2.__proto__ = f(9);` does nothing useful. You're assigning `undefined` as the object from which the `f2` function inherits, and I'm pretty sure this operation is just ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same infinite nesting like

```
look to the right ->             <- look to the left
```

so actually its quite finite ;)

```
prototype ->                   <- constructor
```

( hint: this answer works best on a 300px smartphone..  ;))

Comment: can u please explain it more !

Answer (score 1):

It is the normal behavior. Something like :

```
function f() {
 this.a=0;
}

var obj= new f();
```

Causes the same loop: the constructor for `obj` is `f()`, and the prototype of this constructor has `f()` as constructor, and its prototype has f() as...